# angularjs filter with multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i'm pulling data from an api and displays results in a view. What i want to achieve is being able to filter the data out with multiple parameters

WEB API

```
.controller('list_ctrl',function($scope,$http,$location){
    $scope.loading=true;
    $http.post('http://webapp.com/list.php').success(function(data){
    $scope.complains=data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    $scope.loading=false;

    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td width="6%"><strong>Sort By</strong></td>
    <td width="7%"><select name="select" ng-model="search">
      <option value="$"></option>
      <option value="recieved">Recieved</option>
      <option value="pending">Pending</option>
      <option value="solved">Solved</option>
    </select></td>
    <td width="5%"><strong>Region</strong></td>
    <td width="10%"><select ng-model="region" >
  <option value="" disabled> </option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in complains | unique:'Region'" value="{{item.Region}}">{{item.Region}}</option>

</select></td>
    <td width="5%"><strong>District</strong></td>
    <td width="10%"><select name="select2" ng-model="district" >
      <option value="" disabled="disabled"> </option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in complains | unique:'District'" value="{{item.District}}">{{item.District}}</option>
    </select></td>
    <td width="4%"><strong>Route</strong></td>
    <td width="53%"><select ng-model="route" >
  <option value="" disabled> </option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in complains | unique:'Route'" value="{{item.Route}}">{{item.Route}}</option>

</select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <div align="center" ng-if="loading">
  <img src="img/loader.gif" width="100" height="13" border="0" /> 
</div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <tr class="success">
    <td><strong>Customer Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Account Number</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Complaint Type</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Date of Complaint</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Status</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Options</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in complains | orderBy:'-ID'">
    <td><span ng-class="{'unread':item.View_Status === 'unread'}">{{item.Customer_Name}}</span></td>
    <td>{{item.Account_Number}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Complain_type}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Date_of_Complain |date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Complain_Status}}</td>
    <td><a ng-click="update_view(item)" href="#/complain_view/{{item.ID}}">View</a> | <a ng-click="update_view(item)" href="#/reply/{{item.ID}}">Reply </a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

How do i apply a filter that can sort by region, district and also routes from the above HTML.
Any help with this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please post Fiddle or Plunkr example demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @MaximShoustin, trying to do something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/VTnbqchrdsrN5w0mflji?p=preview